# Fasted Python way to bulk csv convert outside of using pandas

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Im looking for advice on the fasted way to write to csv (not using pandas, that's a last resort). For example, i have 70 files, where each value needs to be inverted. So something like;

```
fname = F1, F2, F3, ...

def csvdump(files)

        date, time, opens, high, low, close, vol = genfromtxt(str(files)+'.csv',unpack=True, delimiter=',')
        for line in high:
                x=str(1/line)
                outr=open(str(files)+"inverse.txt", "a")
                outr.write(x)
                outr.write('\n')
for io in fname:
        csvdump(io)
```

But for 70 files this takes over 3 minutes, is there a faster way of doing it without resorting to learning Pandas?

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where the slowdown is especially as you seem to be opening and closing the same file for every line

Comment: I think it's just a general IO constraint with writing line for line, not too sure; if pandas can do over 1 million rows a minute, i would have thought NumPy was able to do something similar. Ps yes i have tried keeping the file open, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try numpy.savetxt; it seems to be (not quite) three times faster in this test; I have no idea how it scales.  savetxt can add delimiters (see `makebigfile` in the example below).

Some of your code is a bit unusual, like the `str(files)`; I'd expect the filenames to be strings already?

```
import numpy
import timeit


def makebigfile(outname):
    data = numpy.random.standard_normal((100000, 7))
    numpy.savetxt(outname, data, delimiter=",")


def csvdump(files, original=True):

        date, time, opens, high, low, close, vol = numpy.genfromtxt(str(files)+'.csv', unpack=True, delimiter=',')
        if original:
            for line in high:
                x=str(1/line)
                outr=open(str(files)+"inverse-original.txt", "a")
                outr.write(x)
                outr.write('\n')
        else:
            numpy.savetxt(str(files)+"inverse-savetxt.txt",1/high)



makebigfile('foo.txt')


print timeit.timeit(stmt='__main__.csvdump("foo",True)',setup='import __main__',number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(stmt='__main__.csvdump("foo",False)',setup='import __main__',number=1000)
```

On my system this gives:

```
1.41840219498
0.56161403656
```

Comment: Much quicker indeed, quicker, thanks, 3 times quicker. Take care.